# react hooks - get event Object and parameters on button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a button as below

```
<a href="#" className={classes.btnText} onClick={showDetail}>Learn more <span> &rarr; </span> </a>
```

and able to get the event object

```
const showDetail = event => {
        console.log("show detail",event);
    }
```

Now i want to pass an argument on button click. can some one please tell me how to pass event plus an parameter on button click like `showDetail(event, "test")`  and i dont want the function to be invoked until the button is clicked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<a href="#" className={classes.btnText} onClick={(e) => showDetail(e, "test")}>Learn more <span> &rarr; </span> </a>

const showDetail = (event, additionalData) => {
        console.log("show detail", additionalData, event);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Make it a function which returns a function

```js
const showDetail = type => event => {
  console.log("show detail", type, event);
}
```

```js
<a href="#" className={classes.btnText} onClick={showDetail("test")}>
  Learn more <span> &rarr; </span>
</a>
```

this is a currying function, the `type` variable can be accessed from event callback